# No Users and Roles in iTune Connect

Tags: itunes, app-store-connect, developer-program, enterprise

I have registered for Enterprise Apple Developer account and I am a Team Agent. I do not see Users and Roles in iTunes connect and https://developer.apple.com/account/ as well. Below are the screen shot for same -

[image]

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure if this is better here or stackoverflow.com

Comment: In SO there are not enough tags to support this topic. Well asked it both the place which ever gets the answer.